# Error while running Certbot in AWS EC2 CentOS 7.4

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ssl, centos, certbot

When I run `sudo certbot` on terminal

Get following error

```
  [root@ip-111-111-111-111 home]# sudo certbot
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/bin/certbot", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('certbot==1.0.0', 'console_scripts', 'certbot')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 378, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2566, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2260, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certbot/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from certbot._internal import main as internal_main
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certbot/_internal/main.py", line 20, in <module>
    from certbot._internal import client
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certbot/_internal/client.py", line 14, in <module>
    from acme import client as acme_client
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/acme/client.py", line 37, in <module>
    requests.packages.urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl.inject_into_urllib3()  # type: ignore
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 118, in inject_into_urllib3
    _validate_dependencies_met()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 153, in _validate_dependencies_met
    raise ImportError("'pyOpenSSL' module missing required functionality. "
ImportError: 'pyOpenSSL' module missing required functionality. Try upgrading to v0.14 or newer.
```

Comment: What happened when you followed the instructions in the error?

Comment: I have not follow any instructions yet.

Comment: How did you setup certbot? Did you follow [these](https://pocketadmin.tech/en/install-certbot-on-centos/) instructions? These instructions are correct and they work.

Answer (score 2):

In the error, you can find one of the solutions to the error:

```
ImportError: 'pyOpenSSL' module missing required functionality. Try upgrading to v0.14 or newer.
```

Try upgrade the package with the following command:

```
$ pip install "pyOpenSSL>=0.14"
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Certbot is packaged in an extra repository called Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux (EPEL). To enable this repository on CentOS 7, run the following yum command:

```sh
$ sudo yum --enablerepo=extras install epel-release
```

Afterward, the certbot package can be installed with yum:

```sh
$ sudo yum install certbot
```

You may confirm your install was successful by calling the certbot command:

```sh
$ certbot --version
```

**Output:**

```sh
certbot 0.31.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Install it from EPEL.

```
yum install epel-release
yum install certbot
```

`pip` may sometimes not work because of python versions.
Consider certbot a system-wise software.

When I want to install via `pip`, I'd always use `virtualenv`.